# How to perform multiple saving in django?

Tags: django

I am about to perform 3 saves in django. I am worried about race condition and also confused to know if its the correct way to do it !

Here is my code:

```
process.user = user
process.save()

user.is_updated = True
user.save()

actions = Actions(owner=user, action="Personal")
actions.save()
```

I am doing all this in a view function. Is this a right way to do it? Or should i use `@transaction.atomic`? or which is a good method?

Comment: Is user the current user (request.user) ?

Comment: yes correct @amadousow

Comment: I think you are doing nothing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Django code runs sequentially. So there is no race condition.
Transaction is needed when all the saving wokrs altogether. In other words, if any 1 of 3 fail, all fails.

Comment: So what do you recommend for my question ?

Comment: It is up to your requirements. All things must be saved,  then use transaction. Else, you don't need it.